# Disable buttons on rich text input field

Tags: development

Is it possible to disable some of the buttons on the rich text editor field on a text field?

I have set the editor for the text column to accept rich html input, but want to disable/hide some of the buttons that appear in the ribbon then the text box has focus.

I'm new to SharePoint development, so don't know if this is even possible. I've done some searching, but not sure if there is actually a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer to my own question. Using the information at this link:

http://www.directsharepoint.com/2011/03/enable-button-on-ribbon-only-when-user.html

I managed to create a feature to apply to my own custom list type that disables the necessary items on rich text edit boxes.